# Union All alternative

Tags: oracle, performance

I am trying to rewrite a query by removing union all for improving the performance. But not getting clear picture to remove this. Any suggestion would do good. Thanks in Advance.

```
select a.*,"no" as indicator,a.num from a where a=b 
union all 
select a.*,"yes" as indicator,a.num  from a where a=c 
union all
select a.*,"no" as indicator,"All" as num from a where a=b
union all
select a.*,"yes" as indicator,"All" as num from a where a=c  ;
```

Comment: Likely not possible as there are more records in your result set than there are in table `A`. Perhaps multiple joins with some strange coalesce's but... that doesn't feel like a good approach. Or, to put it another way, the result set that you get from this sql is likely only achievable via UNION or... something that is likely much uglier. We would need to understand more about the data though to say that for certain. For instance, is it a rule that either `a=b` or `a=c` and that `a` is never equal to both `b` and `c` at the same time? If not, then you'll need a union to get the same result.

Comment: hi, its basically a same where condition is used for 1st and 3rd union part and same where condition is used for 2nd and 4th union part. 1st union all gives 4000 rows and 2nd union gives around 2400 rows. i am trying to atleast reduce it to 2 union all still it is not working.

Comment: Please share some sample data for the tables used in the query and the result you are expecting from that sample data.

Comment: My point is that you likely can't combine the 1st and 2nd select unless you can say that ((`a=b` or `a=b`) and `b<>c`) in all rows. And you can't combine the 1st and 3rd since it's clear you need two records in your result set where `a=b`. One that has `a.num` and one that has `"All"` in the `num` column. Same logic for the 2nd and 4th selects. In the end, unless ((`a=b` or `a=b`) and `b<>c`) is true for all records, there really isn't any opportunity to get rid of your UNIONs. Can you verify if ((`a=b` or `a=b`) and `b<>c`) either all true or all false for each record in table `a`?

Comment: This seems like a really odd query. You literally want to duplicate each row that matches the filter conditions? (And if there is a row where a = b = c, you'd expect that row to appear 4 times?) What's the purpose of the "All" row? Is there any aggregation in your actual query for the "All" subqueries?

Answer (score 1):

First let me state that the *best optimization* would be if you re-think you approach and change the query to avoid the *redundant output*. - the 3th and 4th provide no new information that is not contained in the first two selects.

Anyway if you want to optimize - this is your approach:

The original query makes four time **full table scan** on your table - you want to do **only one**.

**Sample Data**

```
create table tab as
select 1 a, 2 b, 3 c, '1' num from dual union all
select 1 a, 1 b, 0 c, '2' num from dual union all
select 1 a, 0 b, 1 c, '3' num from dual union all
select 1 a, 0 b, 1 c, '4' num from dual union all
select 1 a, 1 b, 1 c, '5' num from dual;
```

The query leads to the following output

```
select a.a, a.b, a.c, 'no' as indicator,a.num from tab a where a=b 
union all 
select a.a, a.b, a.c, 'yes' as indicator,a.num  from tab a where a=c 
union all
select a.a, a.b, a.c, 'no' as indicator,'All' as num from tab a where a=b
union all
select a.a, a.b, a.c, 'yes' as indicator,'All' as num from tab a where a=c
order by 5,4,1,2,3;



         A          B          C IND NUM
---------- ---------- ---------- --- ---
         1          1          0 no  2  
         1          0          1 yes 3  
         1          0          1 yes 4  
         1          1          1 no  5  
         1          1          1 yes 5  
         1          1          0 no  All
         1          1          1 no  All
         1          0          1 yes All
         1          0          1 yes All
         1          1          1 yes All
```

**New Query**

First scan the table and define the column `a_eq_b` and `a_eq_c` in case that the conditions `a=b`resp. `a=c` holds.

Than join to the `yn` table containing two rows `yes`and `no` with a join condition that either suppress the row  if no condition is met or result in one or two row join simulation your original `union all`.

Finaly introduce your *redundancy* duplication all rows with the additional `All` record joining to the table `All`with two rows.

This query makes only one FTS and provides identical result.

```
with yn as (
select 'yes' indicator from dual union all
select 'no'  from dual),
num as (
select  'All' num from dual union all
select   null from dual),
dt as
(select 
  A, B, C, NUM,
  case when a=b then 'Y' end a_eq_b,
  case when a=c then 'Y' end a_eq_c
from tab)
select dt.A, dt.B, dt.C,
yn.indicator,
nvl(num.num,dt.num) num
from dt
join yn on dt.A_EQ_C = 'Y' and yn.indicator = 'yes'  or dt.A_EQ_B = 'Y' and yn.indicator = 'no'
cross join num
order by 5,4,1,2,3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very odd query indeed but, assuming your example query is representative of what you're trying to achieve, you can rewrite it like so:

```
WITH  a AS (SELECT 1 ID, 1 a, 1 b, 1 c, 10 num FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 ID, 1 a, 3 b, 1 c, 20 num FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, 2 a, 1 b, 1 c, 30 num FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, 2 a, 2 b, 1 c, 40 num FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 ID, 2 a, 1 b, 4 c, 50 num FROM dual), -- you wouldn't need this subquery; you already have an "a" table
  dummy AS (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 ID FROM dual)
SELECT a.*,
       CASE WHEN d.id IN (1, 2) THEN 'no'
            WHEN d.id IN (3, 4) THEN 'yes'
       END indicator,
       CASE WHEN d.id IN (1, 3) THEN to_char(a.num)
            WHEN d.id IN (2, 4) THEN 'All'
       END NUM,
       d.id AS "D.ID"
FROM   a
       INNER JOIN dummy d ON     (a.a = a.b AND d.id IN (1, 2))
                              OR (a.a = a.c AND d.id IN (3, 4))-- each row in the a dataset matching the filter conditions will be returned twice or four times by this join
WHERE  a.a = a.b
OR     a.a = a.c
ORDER BY a.id, a.a, a.b, a.c, d.id;

        ID          A          B          C        NUM INDICATOR NUM        D.ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---- ----------
         1          1          1          1         10 no        10            1
         1          1          1          1         10 no        ALL           2
         1          1          1          1         10 yes       10            3
         1          1          1          1         10 yes       ALL           4
         1          1          3          1         20 yes       20            3
         1          1          3          1         20 yes       ALL           4
         2          2          2          1         40 no        40            1
         2          2          2          1         40 no        ALL           2
```

This basically works by doing a partial cross join of your table's rows with a dummy subquery that has 4 rows (you have two conditions that you want to duplicate rows for, so 2x2 = 4, because presumably you could have a row that matches both conditions).

Once the join has taken place, you can see that the rows that match the `a=b` condition are duplicated with a `d.id` of 1 and 2, and similarly the `a=c` matching rows are duplicated with a `d.id` of 3 and 4. Thus you can use the `d.id` column in case expressions to decide what output to display.

P.s. I've assumed your `num` column is of `NUMBER` datatype, hence the `to_char()` in the second case expression.